# How to read libgtkmm-3.0-doc

Tags: gtkmm

I am learning to use gtkmm and I've downloaded `libgtkmm-3.0-doc` using `apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-doc`. Where do I find this doc so I could read it?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it installs the documentation in html format inside a this path:

`/usr/share/doc/gtkmm-documentation/tutorial/html/index.html`

Comment: One could copy-paste that path on their web browser of choice to access the doc. I did it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the files installed by the package by using the command dpkg-query:

dpkg-query -L libgtkmm-3.0-doc